# How do i plot a normal distrubution with this graph, python/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't find out how to plot a normal distribution for the blue bar-plot in this graph.
The y-axis is made out of an list like this: `[0,0,1,34,.....,34,2,0,0]`
And the x-axis is just: `np.arrange(len(list_above))`

I'very tried several things but all created one vertical line.

So how can i plot a normal distribution for the blue bar-plot?

[image: The graph i have]

Comment: The blue bar plot seems to be sampled from a normal distribution. So it **is** a plot of a normal distribution. Please be precise: What do you want to achieve, what have you tried and where is the problem? [Edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I know that the blue bar ploto looks like a normal deviation but it really isn't. The numbers that resemble the blue bar plot are generated from a tool that rates the similarities between 'sequences'. Because it is so similar to a normal deviation I wanted to see how much it differs from it.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. You might be asking about statistics or programming. You can estimate the mean and standard deviation of this population using the well-known sample statistics, then calculate values of the normal probability density function on the basis of these estimates. You can overlay the histogram you have with a graph of that probability density function using one of the techniques shown in various matplotlib examples. What can we tell you beyond these things?

Answer (score 0):

use matplotlib.pyplot and from scipy.stats import norm

plt.plot(dataset,norm.pdf(dataset,mean of dataset,std of dataset)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).